# Implementing my own interface in VBA - Error: Object module needs to implement 'x' for interface 'y'

Tags: oop, vba, excel

How do I implement my class `ClsInterface`, which has this code:

```
Public Function add(x As Integer, y As Integer) As Integer
End Function
```

in my class `Class2`, which has this code:

```
Implements ClsInterface

Public Function add(x As Integer, y As Integer) As Integer
add = x + y
End Function
```

My test code is

```
Public Sub test()
Dim obj As New Class2
MsgBox obj.add(5, 2)
End Sub
```

This always comes up with the following error:

> Microsoft Visual Basic
>   Compile error:
>
> Object module needs to implement 'add' for interface 'ClsInterface'
>   OK/Help

but there is no help on Microsoft help (when I press on Help button).

Any Ideas?

Comment: Here's [How to use the Implements in Excel VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19373081/how-to-use-the-implements-in-excel-vba/19379641#19379641)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your Class2 must look like:

```
Implements ClsInterface

Private Function ClsInterface_add(x As Integer, y As Integer) As Integer
    ClsInterface_add = x + y
End Function
```

Check out the drop-down boxes at the top of Class2's code window, you can see what base object you can refer to; *Class* or *ClsInterface*.

In your test code you want:

```
Dim obj As New ClsInterface
```

If you want to call across the interface.

I would also recommend naming interfaces in the form `ISomeDescription` and using `Dim` then `Set` rather than `Dim As New`.

Comment: thank you, I followed your instructions it worked without any errors but the value is always 0 !!! while it should be 7, any idea?

Comment: In your Private Function ClsInterface_add... you need 'Return x + y' instead of 'add = x + y', otherwise the value of x+y never gets returned.

Comment: You need to return using; ClsInterface_add = x + y

Comment: this isn't using an interface it's replacing class2 with clsinterface as class

Comment: I just looked for over an hour how to auto-implement a damn COM Interface in VB6 until I found your hint with the Drop-down boxes. Thanks for that.