# VBA Object module must Implement ~?

Tags: vba

I have created two classes, one being an interface for the other. Each time I try to instantiate `Transition_Model` I get:

> Compile error: Object Module needs to implement '~' for interface'~'

To my understanding Implementing class is supposed to have a copy of all public subs, function, & properties. So I don't understant what is the problem here?

Have seen similar questions come up but either they refer to [actual Sub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171324/implementing-my-own-interface-in-vba-error-object-module-needs-to-implement) or they include [other complications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19373081/how-to-use-the-implements-in-excel-vba) making answer too complicated for me to understand.

Also note I tried changing Subs of `Transition_Model` to Private and add 'IModel_' in front of sub names(Just like top answer in second question I linked) but I still receive the same error.

IModel

```
Option Explicit
Public Enum Model_Types
      Transition
      Dummy
End Enum
Property Get M_Type() As Model_Types
End Property
Sub Run(Collat As Collateral)
End Sub
Sub Set_Params(key As String, value As Variant)
End Sub
```

Transition_Model

```
Option Explicit
Implements IModel
Private Transitions As Collection
Private Loan_States As Integer
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set Transitions = New Collection
End Sub
Public Property Get M_Type() As Model_Types
    M_Type = Transition
End Property
Public Sub Run(Collat As Collateral)
    Dim A_Transition  As Transition
    Dim New_Balance() As Double
    Dim Row           As Integer

    For Row = 1 To UBound(Collat.Curr_Balance)
        For Each A_Transition In Transitions
            If A_Transition.Begining = i Then
                New_Balance = New_Balance + Collat.Curr_Balance(Row) * A_Transition.Probability
            End If
        Next A_Transition
    Next
End Sub
Public Sub Set_Params(key As String, value As Double)
    Dim Split_key(1 To 2) As String
    Dim New_Transition As Transition

    Split_key = Split(key, "->")
    Set New_Transition = New Transition

    With New_Transition
        .Begining = Split_key(1)
        .Ending = Split_key(2)
        .Probability = value
    End With

    Transitions.Add New_Transition, key
End Sub
```

Lastly the Sub I am using to test my class

```
Sub Transition_Model()
    Dim Tested_Class As New Transition_Model
    Dim Collat As New Collateral

    'Test is the model type is correct
    Debug.Assert Tested_Class.M_Type = Transition

    'Test if Model without transition indeed does not affect balances of its collateral
    Collat.Curr_Balance(1) = 0.5
    Collat.Curr_Balance(2) = 0.5

    Tested_Class.Run (Collat)

    Debug.Assert ( _
        Collat.Curr_Balance(1) = 0.5 And _
        Collat.Curr_Balance(2) = 0.5)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actaully Per the second question I linked has the correct answer which I missed.

All subs need to start with 'IModel_' and rest ot the name has to match the name in `IModel`.

AND

This is the part i missed, you cannot use underscore in the Sub name.